# can the Open File dialog be used to select a Folder?

Tags: qt, openfiledialog

The "Browse For Folder" Windows dialog is very inconvenient because:

- it has no Path box where I can paste the path I want (eg from Total Commander)
- it always starts from the Desktop with everything closed

Is there a way to use the "Open File" dialog (which is much better) to select a Folder? Some flag or option or something?

Context: the [calibre eLibrary manager](http://bugs.calibre-ebook.com/ticket/7160) which is written in Python and Qt.

It currently displays as on the left. I'd like it to display as on the right
[image: BrowserFileDialog]

or even better, as the Open File dialog:
[image: OpenFileDialog]

Comment: I also hate that you cannot use shortcuts in the "browse for folder" dialog. Why don't they fix it already?!

Answer (score 121):

You can try this one:

```
QString QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory ( QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & caption = QString(), const QString & dir = QString(), Options options = ShowDirsOnly ) [static]
```

This one is used to choose a directory, and will popup a dialog like you show at last.

Demo:

```
 QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                             "/home",
                                             QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                             | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

Answer (score 22):

You can set the file mode in `QFileDialog` to `QFileDialog::Directory`

see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum

Or You can use `QFileDialog::setOption` with value `QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly`

Comment: The [code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kovid/calibre/trunk/annotate/head%3A/src/calibre/gui2/__init__.py#L518) uses QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(QFileDialog.Directory), and this displays the inconvenient "Browse For Folder" dialog.

Comment: Should I use something like this?

dialog = new QFileDialog();

dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, true);

dialog.getOpenFileName(QFileDialog.Directory);

Comment: QFileDialog::DirectoryOnly is obsolete since Qt 4.5:Try using setOption()